# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request, "error": "invalid_scope"

Tags: java, maven, google-analytics-api

We are trying to extract data from Google Analytics using the reporting API.  We have leveraged the "Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; Java quickstart for service accounts" guide to create a test program.  We are getting the following message:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>   {
>   "error": "invalid_scope",
>   "error_description": "Empty or missing scope not allowed."
>   }

Comment: Byron, the Google API requires that you provide a "scope" value when using the API.  Can you edit your question to tell us what scopes you have tried previously?  Alternatively, provide a link to the API documentation about scopes that is causing you confusion.  This helps the reviewers to provide meaningful answers that can guide you to the correct answer.

Comment: That was the problem. Somehow in copying the Google API sample code and modifying it we lost the '.all' value for the scope.  It is working now.

Comment: That was the problem.  Somehow in copying the Google API sample code and modifying it we lost the '.all' value.  It is working now.  Thank you.